# understanding find_if predicate

Tags: predicate, c++

I was going through the following example which I got from another SO post.The example is something like this

```
class checker 
{ 
public:  
    bool operator()(unsigned int i)  
    { 
     if (i%2 == 0)
     {
         return true;   --------------->Statement A
     }
     return false;

    }  
}; 

    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(3);
    vec.push_back(5);
    vec.push_back(2);
    if(std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), checker()) != vec.end())
    {
        std::cout << "Found";
    }
```

Now I have three questions regarding the above example:

Q1- The 3rd parameter of the find_if takes in a predicate . Here I am using a functor object. Is that predicate suppose to be a pointer(address) or an object. Here I am passing an object however in this example at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkwky1wa.aspx) its passing an address. I realize in that example the predicate is not a member method of a class. However I would still appreciate if someone could clarify the requirement of the predicate parameter here. Because if it could accept function pointers then this does not work

```
bool (checker::*aptr)(unsigned int) = NULL;  //Function ptr of class method
aptr = &(checker::operator());
    if(std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), aptr) != vec.end()){...};
```

Q2- Although the above example works fine however when I put a break point at statement A the break point never gets hits and it was suppose to as it returned a true. An clarification on this point would be helpful.

Q3- Some examples have derived the struct /class from `std::unary_function<key_struct, bool>` What is the reason for that. The class above works well for me. Why is there a need to derive it from `std::unary_function<key_struct, bool>` ?

Comment: The predicate can be either a function pointer (like in MSDN example) either a function object instance, which is a class that defines a custom overridden operator for `()`. Both are correct.

Comment: You probably miss a `return false` in the checker::operator(). And you don't need `checker c` in main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The predicate argument may be anything which can be called like a function with the corresponding argument and returning something convertible to `bool`. It can be a function object, i.e., an object of a class with a function call operator, or a function pointer. If you don't modify your object, you should probably make the function call operator `const`.
2. I would *guess* that the function operator ends up being inlined and you put the break point into an out-of-line version of the function object. Setting breakpoints with inlined functions can be tricky. You might want to try making the function non-inline for testing purposes. For production purposes you want to make most predicates `inline` because there is a huge performance difference.
3. When using function object adapters, e.g., `std::not1()` with a function object, they needed to have certain nested types defined. For normal functions the corresponding associated types, e.g., the return type and the argument types, can be deduced easily. For function objects they cannot be deduced in C++03. In C++11 all the nested types aren't necessary (if I recall correctly). In any case, `std::find_if()` doesn't need to mess about the function object beyond calling it, i.e., none of the nested types is actually needed.

BTW, is there any reason your predicate doesn't just return the result of the expression? That is, I would implement it like this:

```
struct checker {
    bool operator()(unsigned int i) const { return (i % 2) == 0; }
};
```

Comment: Tried putting in a function ptr. And it doe snot work. this is what I did  `bool (checker::*aptr)(unsigned int) = NULL;  //Function ptr of class method
aptr = &(checker::operator()); std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), aptr) != vec.end()`

Comment: @MistyD: That's **not** a function pointer but a member function pointer! These are different beasts as they need an additional, normally somewhat hidden, argument: `this`. You cannot use a member function pointer directly where a function object or a function pointer is needed.

Comment: Ok. Then I guess in that case I culd use boost::bind. Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: I tried doing this `checker c;
 bool (checker::*aptr)(unsigned int) =  &(checker::operator()); if(std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), &(c.*aptr)) != vec.end()){..}`

Comment: If you want to use a member function, you need to bind an object, e.g., `std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::bind(&(check::operator()), c, _1))`. Note, however, that using function pointers or member function pointers will be much harder for the compiler to inline and with current compile technology often results in non-inlined code! BTW, the subexpression `&(c.*aptr)` does **not** create a somehow bound member function pointer (I think it is a syntax error).